# Joomla Component Media Manager uploading image to wrong folder

Tags: php, joomla, joomla3.0

I'm using a Joomla 3 extension called Huge-IT Catalog.

https://extensions.joomla.org/extension/catalog/
https://huge-it.com/joomla-catalog-demo-1-block-toggle-updown/
http://huge-it.com/Joom_ext_mod_lite/packages_catalog.3.X.zip (php source here)

---

When uploading an image from the Component, it does not upload to the correct folder. The directories only seem to go 1 sub folder down, but not any further.

I want to upload to `root/catalog/pillows/` but it instead uploads to `root/catalog/`.

This problem is not present in the main Joomla Media Manager, only the Huge-IT Catalog Component Media Manager. I can't tell if the bug is with Joomla or the Component.

---

[image: Media 01]

[image: Media 02]

[image: Media 03]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was with Joomla's media `popup-imagemanager.js`.

Here is the fix, being released in 3.8.9 update. I applied it to the file and it seems to have fixed the problem.

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/20586

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/pull/20586/commits/a80a72eb833fc82c45c41652213369af1990ef77

---

```
getImageFolder: function ()
{
    //return this.getQueryObject(this.frame.location.search.substring(1)).folder;
    return this.getQueryObject(this.frame.location.search.substring(1)).folder.replace(/%2F/gi, "/");
},
```

---

```
setFolder: function (folder, asset, author)
{
    folder = folder.replace(/%2F/gi, "/"); // added this line
    for (var i = 0, l = this.folderlist.length; i < l; i++)
```

Comment: Thank you for self-solving and posting your answer.  Please award your educational answer the green tick.  If you would like to help _more_ Joomla users, perhaps register your account at https://joomla.stackexchange.com/ and post your Joomla-specific Q&A there.